# Configure ui-router with components containing multiple bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I am trying to find a better solution to use the `ui-router` together with `angular components`.

Consider two simple components:

```
app.component('componentOne', {
  template: '<h1>My name is {{$ctrl.name}}, I am {{$ctrl.age}} years old.</h1>',
  bindings : {
      name : '@',
      age : '@'
    }
  }
);

app.component('componentTwo', {
  template: '<h1>I am component 2</h1>'
});
```

Right now, I am specifying the component and its parameter using the `template` property:

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ){
 $stateProvider
    .state('component1', {
      url: "/component1",
      template: "<component-one name=\"foo\" age=\"40\"></component-one>"
    })
    .state('component2', {
      url: "/component2",
      template: "<component-two></component-two>"
    })
});
```

While this is working fine, I have components with arround ten bindings which makes the configuration of the `ui-router` *realy awkward*.

I tried using the `component` property but this doesn't work for me at all. The only other solution I found is to specify the parent using the `require` property and omit the bindings - but this doesn't feel right for me... Is there a better way to do this?

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gmcicmvbsHBCrL7dtAmG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI-Router `component:` routing exists in UI-Router 1.0+ (currently at 1.0.0-beta.1)

Here's an updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/VwhnAvE7uNnvCkrrZ72z?p=preview

#### Bind static values

To bind static data to a component, use `component` and a resolve block which returns static data.

```
$stateProvider.state('component1', {
  url: "/component1",
  component: 'componentOne', 
  resolve: { name: () => 'foo', age: () => 40 }
})
```

#### Bind async values

To bind async values, use a resolve which returns promises for data.  Note that one resolve can depend on a different resolve:

```
$stateProvider.state('component1Async', {
  url: "/component1Async",
  component: "componentOne",
  resolve: {
    data: ($http) => $http.get('asyncFooData.json').then(resp => resp.data),
    name: (data) => data.name,
    age: (data) => data.age
  }
});
```

#### Bind lots of values

You mention you have 10 bindings on a component.  Depending on the structure of the data you're binding, you can use JavaScript to construct the `resolve` block (it's "just javascript" after all)

```
var component2State = {
  name: 'component2',
  url: '/component2',
  component: 'componentTwo',
  resolve: {
    data: ($http) => $http.get('asyncBarData.json').then(resp => resp.data)
  }
}

function addResolve(key) {
  component2State.resolve[key] = ((data) => data[key]);
}

['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux'].forEach(addResolve);

$stateProvider.state(component2State);
```

Comment: very nice. Let me try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can move your bindings a level down and create an object which will be the only bindings. If 10 bindings is what is bothering you.

Comment: Yes, that would work too thus +1. But not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I see. Or there is templateUrl, which makes the configuration less awkward.

Comment: Yes, but then I had to create n html files containing only the template tag (with attributes) which also doesn't feel the right way for me... Maybe someone found a better approach.

Comment: I think this is a completely fine solution. Imagine that the content of the component is 100+ line. That would make your config file with routes really messy ang big. With combination of https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache this feels completely valid. But yes, maybe someone will find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative you can try is to override the template by custom properties of states in `$stateChangeStart` event.

Run block like this to achieve this kind of behaviour.

```
app.run(function($rootScope){

    //listen to $stateChangeStart
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){

    //if the component attribute is set, override the template
    if(toState.component){


      //create element based on the component name
      var ele = angular.element(document.createElement(camelCaseToDash(toState.component)));

      //if there is any binding, add them to the element's attributes.
      if(toState.componentBindings){
        angular.forEach(toState.componentBindings,function(value,key){
          ele.attr(key,value)
        })
      }

      //you may also do something like getting bindings from toParams here

      //override the template of state
      toState.template = ele[0].outerHTML;
    }


  })

  //convert camel case string to dash case
  function camelCaseToDash(name) {
    return name.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
  }

})
```

And with this now you can have `component` property in your state config.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ){
 $stateProvider
    .state('component1', {
      url: "/component1",
      component:"componentOne",
      componentBindings:{
        name:"foo",
        age:"40",
      }
    })
    .state('component2', {
      url: "/component2",
      component:"componentTwo",
    })
});
```

Here is the working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GNAWCqtKcKk8BIXUKtWV?p=preview).

Still you may have a large config function, but it will look not so awkward.

Comment: Thanks for that one, the config now looks much cleaner. I was hopping to find a built-in solution but If no one come with a better approach I will accept the answer in a few days.